# How to refer to an "owner class" in C++?

Tags: c++, class, this

I have code that looks like this:

```
template<class T>
class list
{
public:
    class iterator;
};

template<class T>
class list::iterator
{
public:
    iterator();
protected:
    list* lstptr;
};

list<T>::iterator::iterator()
{
    //???
}
```

I want to make the constructor of `list::iterator` to make `iterator::lstptr` point to the list it's called from.  I.e.:

```
list xlst;
xlst::iterator xitr;
//xitr.lstptr = xlst
```

How would I do that?

And also, am I referencing my iterator-constructor right, or should I do something like this:

```
template<class T>
class list<T>::iterator
{
public:
    list<T>::iterator();
protected:
    list* lstptr;
};
```

Comment: Have you tried the code you commented out in the second block? I am don't know c++ (only C) and that looks like what I would do.

Comment: Your last version of iterator is correct if you change the ctor from list<T>::iterator(); -> iterator(); cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the list to the constructor of iterator:

```
list xlst;
list::iterator xitr(xlst);
```

Or, you could make an iterator factory function:

```
list xlst;
list::iterator xitr = xlst.create_iter();
```

In the factory function case, the `create_iter()` function can use `this` to refer to the enclosing list.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to do that, until I relized I should be able to make the iterator equal to it's calling class.

Then I reade your answer and relized that I would call iterator with "list::iterator" and not "xlst::iterator".  My goal was to recreate some aspects of "vector".

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need to change (reseat) the pointer and there's no need for the NULL value, I would instead use a reference. Also you can use an initializer list when assigning the member variable (and have to if you're using a reference).

```
template<class T>
class list::iterator
{
public:
    iterator( list& parent ) : lstptr( parent ){}

protected:
    list& lstptr;
};
```

And as mentioned before: use a factory method inside the list class to construct objects of type list::iterator.